# Why can I run KinD code but get wrong results?

Tags: image-processing, image-enhancement

l am new to image processing.I ran the code given by the author of KinD(the corresponding paper is Kindling the Darkness--A Practical Low-light Image Enhancer), used the author's pre-trained network, and ran the "evaluate.py" file, and then I got the results, but the output images did not correct.

The first image is the low-light image given by the author for testing, and the followings are the outputs of "adjust_i","decom_i_low","decom_r_low","denoise_r" and "kindle".Why could this happen? Thanks for your help!

origin `https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2WB1.jpg`

adjust_i `https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkKho.png`

decom_i_low `https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT4Yp.png`

decom_r_low `https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBA3P.png`

denoise_r `https://i.stack.imgur.com/am4Th.png`

kindle `https://i.stack.imgur.com/cunF5.png`